# Maximum data transfer over Ethernet

Tags: linux, ftp, file-transfer

I'm trying to check what the maximum transfer speed is over ethernet. In my local network I want the communication between a Linux device and a Microsoft machine.

I tried using `dd if=/dev/zero | ssh user@ip` to the Microsoft machine but it doens't accept the `dd` command. I tried `scp` but is not able to send `dev/zero`. I read about the `pv` command but I don't want to install additional software on the Linux device.

Maybe it is possible to use a FTP client on the Microsoft machine and download the `dev/zero` to get an infinite stream of data, and while it is downloading run a script like this (https://gist.github.com/cjsewell/96463db7fec6faeab291) to check the transfer speed.

Any suggestions for a better way?

Comment: iperf3 is available both for Linux and Windows.

Comment: Your command `dd if=/dev/zero | ssh user@ip` would try to run a command on the remote system consisting of a stream of null bytes. (That isn't a command.) That's supposing your Microsoft machine has an `ssh` service, which most don't. What do you mean by "_it doesn't accept the `dd` command_"? Please provide details. You seem to be muddling `/dev/zero` with `dev/zero` (missing the leading `/`). Details are important.

Comment: @roaima, I was hoping this would start an infinit stream of 0's to a file on the windows machine. `dd if=/dev/zero | ssh Piet@192.168.1.118 dd of=/C:/Users/Piet/text.txt`
Piet@192.168.1.118's password:
dd is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

But even if this works, it is in SSH, which I don't want.

Comment: But that's not what you wrote in your question. Please correct your question to show the full command and the error message

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to check what the maximum transfer speed is over ethernet. In my local network I want the communication between a Linux device and a Microsoft machine.

suggest you keep it simple, you don't need to do a *stream an infinite zeros*.

- Install samba [server] on linux and open a shared folder such as `/tmp`.
- On linux if it's a *systemd* type system, do a `systemctl enable tmpfs.mount` followed by a reboot.  This will put the `/tmp` folder in ram and will prevent disk i/o from messing up the transfer numbers.  This way it will all be in RAM and the slowest thing happening will be the transfer over ethernet whatever those hops may be.
- create some .tar file sized around 10gb, do larger if you like to test transfer speed over a longer duration.
- connect to your linux server from your windows machine making use of the samba setup, move the ~10gb file back and forth and observe the transfer speed in the popup on windows.

from linux to linux, make use of secure copy `scp` which is over SSH and you will notice some reduction because of the overhead of SSH.  It neatly prints out the transfer speed for you when doing `scp`.

on a 1gbps wired network, such as 2 systems next to each other over a 6' cat6 cable, I see a solid 112 MB/sec transfer speed between windows and linux.

Over SSH with secure copy on a **LAN** having a few switches (not routers) it is often around 80 MB/sec; this is on rhel 7.

1gbps = 1000 mbit per sec, and is *theoretical* not accounting for ethernet overhead.  1000 / (8 bits per byte ) = 125 MB/sec maximum theoretical.  Seeing ~112 MB/sec is 89.6%.   I have never experienced larger than 113 mb/sec on a 1gbps wired network shown on that pop on the windows machine.

fwiw:  just did a 7.6gb tar file over `scp` between two rhel 7.9 systems on a 1gbps wired network in work environment, so figure at least 2 [expensive] cisco routers present.  Everything within the building.  From a server having 512gb ram, secure copied to a pc having an ssd and 16gb ram.  SCP finished in 1:11 and and said at the end 106.5 MB/s.  So consider as a baseline a 106 mb/s vs 112 mb/s transfer speed... 84.8% vs 89.6% and the ballpark reduction in speed due to ssh overhead.

Comment: fyi:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/506910/creating-a-large-size-file-in-less-time

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to say. Excellent answer.